# Showing custom dialog instead of "ANR dialog"

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

i want to show customize dialog instead of ANR dialog. I know all about avoiding ANR but nowadays i am working on a very big code base and now instead of re vamping the code i want to know is there any way to override anr dialog? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot "override anr dialog".

Comment: is there any way to snub the call like thread.uncaughexceptionhandler does with force close ?

Comment: @lee lias: Not that I am aware of.